# Настройка шрифтов в Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, centos, консоль

Не могу понять как настроить шрифты.

1. Узнать какой шрифт используется в консоли
2. Узнать какой размер шрифта используется
3. Установить нужный шрифт и размер шрифта для консоли
4. Узнать установленное разрешение экрана

Comment: Вы бы уточнили, о какой именно консоли говорится. А то может это монитор геркулес и нужно знакогенератор зашивать

Comment: @KoVadim имею ввиду консоль через монитор или эммуляция через KVM&Proxmox

Comment: обычно всё это просто прописывается в системных конфигах и ни кто не задаётся целью запрашивать эту информацию у системы... так что вопрос желательно сдабдить хоть какой-то мотивацией, еже ли это не просто праздный интерес... и для определённости, какая консоль всё же имеется ввиду, VGA'шная, фреймбуферная (с каким драйвером фреймбуфера?) или X-терминал?... затравки ради, для дебиана можно почитать, например `man 5 console-setup`.

Comment: @user8501933 у вас эмулятор в GUI или tty?

Comment: @Hellseher tty через монитор

Comment: @Hellseher https://forum.ubuntu.ru/index.php?topic=105408.msg790841#msg790841 я не могу понять почему именно так до сих пор решается вопрос с разрешением экрана... Проблема уже больше 3 лет не решается

Comment: @user8501933 попробуйте fbset, хорошая документация.

Answer (score 2):

Для Debian/Ubuntu:

```
~# dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

Для дистрибутивов с systemd:

```
~# systemctl restart systemd-vconsole-setup.service
```

Полезные утилиты:

```
loadkeys — load keyboard translation tables
setfont - load EGA/VGA console screen font
fbset - show and modify frame buffer device settings
```

Файлы:

- /usr/lib/kbd/consolefonts консольные шрифты
- /etc/vconsole.conf
- /lib/kbd/consolefonts/ доступные шрифты (Fedora)
- /etc/default/grub настройки по умолчанию GRUB для разрешения и шрифтов

**Ссылки**

- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-vconsole-setup.service.html
- https://github.com/Hellseher/cix/blob/master/conf/cix-grub.cfg
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fb/framebuffer.txt
- https://linux.die.net/man/8/fbset